# Static library cannot open include file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, static-libraries

I created a static library (Engine) and an application (Game). They are both linked and work properly with each other. But if I include one of the headers from the static library (Class.h), in which the header itself includes another header (SDL.h), I get an error saying that it cannot open the include file.

Game Code (Game.cpp):

```
#include "Class.h"

void main()
{
    Class a;
    a.Print();
    while (true);
}
```

Engine code:
(Class.h)

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL2\SDL.h"

class Class
{
public:
    void Print();
};
```

(Class.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"

void Class::Print()
{
    std::cout << "Working" << std::endl;
}
```

The SDL2\SDL.h is in a folder called include and is included in the Engine static library, the engine can use things from that header, but when I try to run the game it gives me this error.

```
C1083 Cannot open include file 'SDL2\SDL.h': No such file or directory
```

If you know why this is happening please do let me know.

Comment: That means you need to fix your include path so that the folder containing the `SDL` folder is in your compilers includes when using the Class.h header. If both the Engine and Game need to include SDL in a header they both have to have the folder containing SDL in the include directories for these 2 projects.

Comment: I have my Include folder included in the Additional Incude Directories. Do I need to include it somewhere else?

Comment: You need to include it in `Additional Incude Directories` for both Engine and Game projects and all configurations you use. And remember you need to include the parent folder that contains `SDL` so that the relative path `SDL2\SDL.h` is found.

Comment: (Answered)
Ok it works now I thought it would include it as well with the other file. Thanks!

Comment: A project does not inherit the includes of the dependent project by default. I know there is a way when using CMake to do this but not sure about VS alone.